# Firebase requireAuth not working

Tags: firebase-authentication

I am having a hard time doing the requireAuth to work. I have tried both the ngroute and uirouter and if the user doesn't login, I just want to redirect him back to the home page.

In my app, I have 1 page with multiple controllers where I want to set the above rule.

This is the factory and run method:

```
app.factory("AuthFactory", ["$firebaseAuth", function($firebaseAuth) {
  var ref = new Firebase("https://torrid-heat-237.firebaseio.com");
  return $firebaseAuth(ref);
  }
]);

// for ui-router
app.run(["$rootScope", "$state", function($rootScope, $state) {
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
  // We can catch the error thrown when the $requireAuth promise is rejected
  // and redirect the user back to the home page
  if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
    $state.go("/");
  }
});
}]);
```

The, I have written a .state method:

```
app.config(["$stateProvider", function ($stateProvider) {
$stateProvider
    .state('geniuses', {
      url: '/geniuses',
      abstract: true,
      controller: 'GetAllGeniuses',
      templateUrl: "views/listAllgeniuses",
      resolve: {
        "currentAuth": ["AuthFactory", function(AuthFactory) {
          return AuthFactory.$requireAuth();
        }]
      }
    }).state('geniuses', {
      url: '/geniuses',
      abstract: true,
      controller: 'SearchAGenius',
      templateUrl: "views/listAllgeniuses",
      resolve: {
        "currentAuth": ["AuthFactory", function(AuthFactory) {
          return AuthFactory.$requireAuth();
        }]
      }
    })
}]);
```

And lastly, in both the controllers, I am waiting for the AuthFactory.requireAuth to resolve. But, what happens is when I hit the url w/o logging in, it stays there itself and even when I do login, it displays the same kind of page..

What exactly is it that I have done wrongly here?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

And finally can solved it.

Be sure you are calling $unauth() on logout. First time you logged in it will be fine. The real problem appears when you close the session without $unauth().

So, if you have a function to logout use this:

```
AuthFactory.$unauth();
```

This is an example from my code:

```
app.factory('Auth', ["$firebaseAuth","settings",
function($firebaseAuth,settings){

return {
    oauth: function() {

      var ref = new Firebase(settings.firebaseBaseUrl);

      return $firebaseAuth(ref);
    }
}]);



.state("votes",{
  url:"/restaurant/poll",
  views:{
    "main":{
      templateUrl:"views/restaurant/poll/main.html",
      controller: "pollsController"
    }
  },
  data: {pageTitle:'Encuesta'},
  resolve: {
    "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
      return Auth.oauth().$requireAuth();
    }]
  }
});


app.run(function($rootScope,settings, $state, $location, $localStorage, Auth) {

  $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
    if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
      $state.go('home');
    }
});
```

And Finally:

```
MetronicApp.controller('HeaderController', ['$scope', "$rootScope", "Auth", "$state", "$localStorage", "toaster",
function($scope, $rootScope, Auth, $state, $localStorage) {


  $rootScope.logout = function(to){
    to = to == undefined ? 'home' : to;
    Auth.oauth().$unauth();
    $state.go(to);
  };


}]);
```